# Get the height and width of the window inside which the view is placed

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, dimensions

I have a customised view `CustomView` which I place inside the layout of my activity. Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <com.musicmuni.riyaz.views.CustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/view2"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, you see that my `CustomView` is placed towards right of a `View` with id `view1` and below a `View` with id `view2`. What I do is set the width of `CustomView` based on my need by overriding `onMeasure`, so that I can scroll over my `CustomView`. I still need the window size inside which my `CustomView` has been placed. So lets say the screen dimension is `1200px X 800px` and the height of `view1` is `150px` and the width of `view2` is `60px`, then the window size of `CustomView` should be `1050px X 740px`. How can I get this number? If I will use `CustomView.getWidth()`, it will give me the width of the view that I had set inside `onMeasure`. What is the way to get the correct window size?

**Edit 1**:

Here is a drawing of what I want to achieve. Hope this makes it more clear:
[image]

Comment: You could set your `CustomView` to have both `layout_height`and `layout_width` to **0dp** and have `layout_weight` equals to **1**. It will take the rest of the space. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: I think you did not understand the question correctly. I have no problem in having my view occupying the entire space. I am not sure how to find out the actual width and height occupied by my view on the screen.

Comment: I understand now. But do you want to just get the size of your custom view? If so, `getWidth` and `getHeight` should do the work. Maybe you are calling it before the size is defined? Try to call it on `onResume` inside your activity.

Comment: No, I want to get the dimension of the area over the physical screen inside which my view has been put. That can be different from the actual dimensions of the view. For example, the case of a view which is scrollable, the actual width got by `getWidth()` is different from the dimension of the physical space inside which I see my view.

Comment: Well... You would need to list manually your views, get the screen/display size and do the math. I don't recommend you to get all views programmatically, because a view can be inside a group view, so the math wouldn't match. How to get screen dimensions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels

Comment: I have added a drawing in the question to be more clear on what I am saying. Hope this helps.